# Reading duplicate headings following by data from a file AND writing to a different file with single unique heading and all data

Tags: perl, file-io

## my data

```
shift 01
 
data

data

data 

shift 02

data
 
data

data

shift 01
 
data

data
 
data

shift 02 

data

data

data
```

---

## what i am trying to do

```
shift 01
    
data

data

data

data

data

data

shift 02

data

data

data

data

data

data
```

my code:

```
my @data = 'FILE' ;

if ($linee =~ /$Pattern/){

if (! exists $badge{$1} ) { 
$match[$i] = $1 ;
}
}

foreach (@data) {

do {

print "$linee";

} until ($match[$i] == $data[$_] ) ;
 $i++ ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an Hash of Arrays like so ...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my %hash;
my $key;

while(<DATA>) {
        # get rid of line feed char
        chomp;

        # skip empty lines
        next if /^$/;

        # detected shift change otherwise it's data to associate with the current shift
        if ( /^shift/ ) {
                $key=$_;
        } else { 
                push(@{$hash{$key}},$_);
        }
}

# output our data structure
for $key ( sort keys %hash ) {
        print "shift=>$key\n";
        for my $data ( @{$hash{$key}} ) {
                print "$data\n";
        }
}


__DATA__
shift 01

data

data

data

shift 02

data

data

data

shift 01

data

data

data

shift 02

data

data

data
```

Comment: Your welcome.  If you can please "accept" the answer.  I forget whether or not there are reputation score restrictions.